# ID auto added in the POST url

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an edit View in my application.This is my `Razor syntax` for `POSTing` a `form`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "person", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

After I run my application, inspect the markup in browser, following `markup` is generated

`<form method="post" action="/person/edit/1"`>

I want the `url` to be `"/person/edit"` in another `POST` action

This is my `action` method in `Controller`

```
[Route("edit/{person_id}")]
public IActionResult edit(long person_id)
{
    //some stuffs
    return View();
}
```

Comment: And your problem???

Comment: @MRebati question clearly states that ID is auto- added. I need the url in "/person/edit" format

Comment: then don't use the razor. it just creates the prefered HTML codes. so just write the desired HTML.

Comment: @MRebati that anti-forgery token won't be validated doing so. Or does it?

Comment: do you see anything unusual in your generated HTML form? if not then it has nothing to do with the razor generator.

Comment: @MRebati I wonder how Id got added in that generated URL until I added values explicitly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177121/discussion-between-mrebati-and-dot-net-developer).

Comment: Why do you not want the id there? It's necessary, as that's what identifies the resource that's being edited. With the id in the URL you can enforce access control, if necessary. If you're relying on the id being posted, you're opening a gaping security hole.

Comment: You can use `@using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "person", new { person_id = "" }, FormMethod.Post))`, but its not clear why you want to remove it.

Comment: Because I want to make POST request in another action method with route "/person/edit" . Thank u sir for your comment. I don't know ID was appended in URL although I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `RouteData.Values.Remove("person_id");` in the `action` before returning the `View`  worked for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020253/calling-html-beginform-and-specifying-action](http://reference%20link)